# Rotating image results in java.lang.NullPointerException after a number of rotations

Tags: java, android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, rotation

In my app, I have it so that a `button` rotates a `bitmap` 90 degrees each time it is pressed. I have another `button` that does the same thing but rotates the `bitmap` -90 degrees.

My issues is that after I press the rotate `buttons` about 4-6 times, it varies per picture, in any order, I get the error:

```
    `java.lang.NullPointerException`: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference.
```

Why is this error occurring when the rotation fxn works fine the first few times? I have noticed that the width and height of the bitmap increase each time the rotate `button` is pushed but that shouldn't crash the app if they are larger than the `imageview`. I've tried multiple other methods but they seem to crash or just shrink the image.

**This is my code:**

```
    rotateClockWise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap bitmap = imageViewtoBitmap(imageView);
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(width));
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();
            Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(height));
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                    width, height, matrix, true );

            imageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);

        }
    });

    rotateCCW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap bitmap = imageViewtoBitmap(imageView);
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(width));
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();
            Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(height));
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(-90);

            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true );

            imageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);

        }
    });

public static Bitmap imageViewtoBitmap(ImageView imageView){
    /**
     * Args:
     *     imageview: an imageview
     * Returns:
     *     the bitmap of the imageview
     */

    //convert imageview to bitmap
    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will 
 be null
    imageView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, 
    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, 
    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    // hardcoded so i always know how big image is
    imageView.layout(0, 0, imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), 
    imageView.getMeasuredHeight());
    if (imageView == null){
        Log.i(TAG, "nothing");
    }
    imageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache

    return bitmapImage;


}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole exception stack

Answer (score 0):

You should delay click.

Example

in onCreate()

```
 rotateClockWise.setOnClickListener(this);
 rotateCCW.setOnClickListener(this);
```

in method onClick

```
private long lastClick = 1;

void onClick(View view) {
    if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClick < 500) return;
       lastClick = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.rotateClockWise: // change id of rotateClockWise
         break;
        case R.id.rotateCCW: // change id of rotateCCW
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post method imageViewtoBitmap ?

Comment: Code has been added.

Comment: What's the exception stack?